# Not able to write image in shared folder in IIS

Tags: iis, c#-4.0

I have developed an module to save image in windows shared location 
my code works fine development machine in VS 2015 and IIS express.

But when i deploy the code in my IIS sever(IIS 8) and set my appppol.
When it checks the directory exists or no it fails and does not save the image.
in share path. I have tried accessing the shared path from server I am able to open it without issues

I have applied logs to check but it fails that directory does not exit
Sharepath ex:\atse-bs-13450.abc.xyz.com\Sharefolder\PhotoImages

My app pool  is set to ApplicationPoolIdentity

```
 public void WriteImage(string Location, string base64Image)
{
    try
    {
        // Check if directory exist 
        if (Directory.Exists(Location))
        {
    //location  value is set in appSettings;
    //"\\atse-bs-13450.abc.xyz.com\Sharefolder\PhotoImages\"
            string strImagePath = Location;
            // Check file exist in location 
            if (!File.Exists(Location))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64Image))
                {
                    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(strImagePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                    {
                        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
                        writer.Write(Base64String2Blob(base64Image));
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                strBlobLogMessage = "image file could not be stored on shared location , Share path location : ";
                PathNotFound(strBlobLogMessage);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            strBlobLogMessage = "image file could not be stored on shared location as path does not exists , Share path location : ";
            PathNotFound(strBlobLogMessage);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

Comment: do `IIS_IUSRS` and `IUSR` have permission on that folder?

Comment: @PriyeshKumar since app pool identity is set to `Application Pool Identity` the website will run under it not IIS_IUSRS

Answer (score 1):

Two options

1. Create a user account and then assign that user account read and write access on shared location. Then you can set the Application Pool Identity to `Custom account` and then set it to newly created user account.

[image]

2. Since your app pool is using Application Pool Identity, there will be user account with name `IIS AppPool\{Applicaiton Pool name}` e.g. for DefaultAppPool the user account is `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` so you can allow read/write access to shared directory to Applicaiton Pool user

[image]

Comment: If that solution worked for you, please mark it as an answer